# How do you use Python to create a docx file, where you have MathML code, that displays the mathematical notation on the created docx file?

Tags: math, mathjax, python-docx

I have some MathML code which when I put on an HTML file, it displays the equation properly. But the same doesn't happen when I try to put it on an MS Word document using the docx Python library. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I have:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph()
p.text = ('<math display="block"><mrow><mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo><mfrac><mrow><mrow><mo>-</mo><mi>b</mi></mrow><mo>&PlusMinus;</mo><msqrt><mrow><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>4</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>a</mi><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>c</mi></mrow></mrow></msqrt></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>a</mi></mrow></mfrac></mrow></math>')
document.save("simpleEq.docx")
```

I did see a Python script online that mentioned something about "MML2OMML.XSL", but I don't think I have that file as part of my MS Word, and I don't know where to download it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MS Word is a difficult environment for handling equations, among other things. Maybe you can say more about the larger goals of your project; it may turn out that you can use some other document format.

Comment: I'm just trying to see if it would be possible to put math equations in MS Word, programmatically, so I can create worksheets for my students. I imagine that's how a lot of companies who create worksheets do it.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Given that, my advice is to work with pandoc (a web search will find it) and write your base document in markdown format or something like that, and then generate HTML or PDF from that. I think pandoc might be able to generate MS Word documents but I'm not sure if it can, and even if it does, equations and figures might be a challenge.

Comment: I think that there has been a lot of interest in generating educational documents using Python and other tools, so maybe expressing your goals in those terms might be a way to align with stuff that people are already working on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I think I got the closest solution so far from stumbling on this page:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/320

The only issue is that mathML like &PlusMinus; and &InvisibleTimes; isn't being recognized.